# Concatenating a dictionary item with a string inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, concatenation

so I'm trying to create the game Yahtzee in python, and I'm trying to put up points inside a table I created. although, because strings are immutable, I tried to retrieve a dictionary item from inside the list (which comprises the table) and concatenate it with the rest of the string. but for some reason my output just excludes the dictionary item as if it's not there.

here is the code:

```
points = {
    "1" : "Ones",
    "2" : "Twos",
    "3" : "Threes",
    "4" : "Fours",
    "5" : "Fives",
    "6" : "Sixes"
}


avaliable_grid = [
    " _____________________________          _____________________________",
    "|           |Player 1|Player 2|        |           |Player 1|Player 2|",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|Ones       |" + points["1"] + "|        |        |3 of a Kind|        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|Twos       |" + points["2"] + "|        |        |4 of a Kind|        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|Threes     |" + points["3"] + " |        |        |Full House |        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|Fours      |" + points["4"] + "|        |        |S. Straight|        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|Fives      |" + points["5"] + "|        |        |L. Straight|        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|Sixes      |" + points["6"] + "|        |        |Chance     |        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|#############################|        |YAHTZEE    |        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|Sum        |        |        |        |#############################|",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|Bonus      |        |        |        |TOTAL SCORE|        |        |",
    " -----------------------------          ----------------------------- ",
    ]


def print_table(table):
    for i in table:
        print(i)

print_table(avaliable_grid)
```

output:

```
 _____________________________          _____________________________
|           |Player 1|Player 2|        |           |Player 1|Player 2|
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Ones       |        |        |        |3 of a Kind|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Twos       |        |        |        |4 of a Kind|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Threes     |        |        |        |Full House |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Fours      |        |        |        |S. Straight|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Fives      |        |        |        |L. Straight|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Sixes      |        |        |        |Chance     |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|#############################|        |YAHTZEE    |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Sum        |        |        |        |#############################|
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Bonus      |        |        |        |TOTAL SCORE|        |        |
 -----------------------------          -----------------------------
```

for some reason, the `points[]` dictionary is ignored. also, the way I am printing this is like that because I want it to print row by row, without parenthesis, or quotation marks.

for reference- I am using python 3.8.2, and I'm working through IDLE.

Comment: it worked well when i ran it.

Comment: Try running it somewhere else, I think you are using IDLE wrong.

Comment: where else can I run it? fairly new to the python game, and I have no clue where I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm new and can't comment I'm just going to guess what the rest of your code could look like.
I started by adding this to try and reproduce your output.

```py
for row in avaliable_grid:
    print(row)
```

The output:

```py
_____________________________          _____________________________
|           |Player 1|Player 2|        |           |Player 1|Player 2|
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Ones       |Ones|        |        |3 of a Kind|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Twos       |Twos|        |        |4 of a Kind|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Threes     |Threes |        |        |Full House |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Fours      |Fours|        |        |S. Straight|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Fives      |Fives|        |        |L. Straight|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Sixes      |Sixes|        |        |Chance     |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|#############################|        |YAHTZEE    |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Sum        |        |        |        |#############################|
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Bonus      |        |        |        |TOTAL SCORE|        |        |
 -----------------------------          -----------------------------
```

So, in my output, I think your code works as intended. Could you explain what you used to actually print the output?

edit: obviously there's still some formatting to do, maybe you could try using the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) or `\t`, or maybe the simplest thing would be to just add trailing space characters to each of your dictionary values to have their lengths matching and adjust the card accordingly.

```py
points = {
    "1" : "Ones  ",
    "2" : "Twos  ",
    "3" : "Threes",
    "4" : "Fours ",
    "5" : "Fives ",
    "6" : "Sixes "
}
```

edit2: since you're using python 3.8, you could use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) (f-strings). They're a really fast and readable way to format your strings dynamically.
You do this by adding curly braces around python code within a string and prepending an `f` character before opening the string like so:

```py
f"|Ones       | {points["1"]} |        |        |3 of a Kind|        |"
```

Comment: I edited the post to include the exact code I use to print it, but it seems that it is the same code that you have. I just made it a function because I need to print multiple tables.

Comment: I see! Good to know we're printing the table in the same way, did you manage to have the dictionary values printed the way you wanted?

Comment: I didn't. this method of using a `for` loop is the one I used since before I posted the question... also, I am definitely going to use the f-strings, that looks really useful, thanks :)

Comment: When I run the code with the newly added print function, it still works fine for me -- in IDLE --, except the formatting is just a bit off. Do the dictionary values still not show up for you?

Comment: I just understood what I did wrong, and I feel like such an idiot. a few lines after I defined `available_grid` I defined it again as a blank version of the grid. Point is, I made a very stupid mistake. I will most defiantly still use your advice, the f strings are easier. thanks and honestly sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: Hey, no worries! In the future I can suggest a bit of [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :p. And about the fstrings, spread the word! I heared they are even faster than former methods and I haven't met many people that use them yet.

Comment: I have another question very quickly- I managed to make this work, but the only problem is that it's not updating. the reason I made the dictionary in the first place is because I knew I can rewrite it, but for some reason, it's not updating on the grid. what I mean by that, is that I updated the dictionary after defining `available_grid`, and the printed version of the grid is the same as the old dictionary, even though the dictionary has indeed been changed (I checked by printing the dictionary after changing it). like, does the f string not update or something?

Comment: If you make sure your dictionary[key] points to the correct value, `f'{dict[key]}' should display that value. You'll have to re-print the whole card when you make a change to the dictionary.

Comment: I managed ti fix this since posting the comment, and you were 100% correct- i had the ```dictionary[key]``` to the wrong value. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ah, glad it worked out. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.
(stole this from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on), as I thought it would be rude to ask but since we're both quite new, I thought I'd give it a shot.